# How to Replace a column in one file with shell script variable and keep the Double quotes that are part of the column with an awk statement

Tags: bash, awk, double-quotes

Line in file:

```
where so.name ="tblname"
```

shell script variable being set with:

```
for tablename in `cat $TBLNAME.$DBNAM.out`
```

`awk` statement in shell script:

```
awk -v xy="$tablename" '$1=="where"{$4='\"xy\"'}1' $COLMNAME > tmp2 && mv tmp2 $COLMNAME
```

Line in output file after awk statement executed:

```
where so.name = xy
```

what I want is:

```
where so.name = "tbuser"
```

Comment: You should copy/paste your whole shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it will tell you about.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape double quotes inside there (without using single quotes).

```
awk -v xy="$tablename" '$1=="where"{$4="\""xy"\""}1' file
```